# How to split a string by space+ escaping initial spaces in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have:

```
String s = "Hello    world";
```

or

```
String s = "   Hello    world ";
```

the result should be:

```
String[] splited = s.split("REGEX");
splited[0].equals("   Hello"); \\true
splited[1].equals("world "); \\true
```

I did like this: `s.trim().split(" +");` but I have lost first spaces in splited[0], but the space should stay.

- How can I do it whith regex?

Comment: @anubhava i think the OP means split `"   Hello    word "` into `"   Hello"` and `"word "` keeping the trailing end space.

Comment: @anubhava basically it sounds like the OP just wants to keep any trailing and ending white space, whether there is any or not.  The first line showing no trailing or ending white space while the second has it.  When the OP says _the result should be: ..._ I take that as to mean only for the second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine negative [look ahead/behind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
String[] array = s.split("(?<!^\\s*)\\s+(?=\\S)");
```

- `(?<!^\\s*)` Match start of string + `0` or more whitespaces
- `(?=\\S)` Match non-whitespace

Comment: What about the trailing spaces?

Comment: i think it would be `"(?<!^\\s*)\\s+(?=\\S)"`

Comment: offered credit for both ... :-) I don't know why `"(?<=^\\s*\\S+)\\s+"` fails and this `"(?<=^\\s*)\\s+"` works. Both are variable length lookbehind assertions.

Answer (score 1):

A limited (to 1000 spaces at the begining) way:

```
String[] splited = s.split("(?<!\\A\\s{0,1000})\\s+(?=\\S)");
```

details:

```
(?<!\\A\\s{0,1000}) # not preceded by white-spaces at the start of the string
\\s+                # white-spaces
(?=\\S)             # followed by a non white-space character
```

or the same strictly for spaces (not for tabs or newlines...):

```
String[] splited = s.split("(?<!\\A {0,1000}) +(?=[^ ])");
```

Comment: is that the case, you could use `"(?<=\\A\\s{0,1000}\\S{1,1000})\\s+"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: why not, but this will  work if you want to split the string in only two parts, not for more. (I think the OP try to avoid the empty strings as first and probably last item).

Comment: unlimited lookbehinds are "generaly" not possible with java, you can use variable length lookbehinds, but they need to have a limited length.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: the java regex engine is know to be buggy, in particular for this feature (there are many topics about that). But officially, only limited lengths are allowed.